# How to re-sign an iOS app that has a Framework?

Tags: ios, xamarin, codesign

I've been trying to re-sign an `.ipa` file with a customer's certificate and provisioning profile. I used the command:

`codesign -f --deep -s "Customer Certificate" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/MyApp.app`

However, after I install the application on a device, it crashes on startup with the following error:

```
kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 1240) - [deny-mmap] mapped file does not the same team identifier as main process: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BDB7DDBF-E298-4B68-8567/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libskia_ios.framework/libskia_ios
kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 1240) - [deny-mmap] process has team identifier U78696: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BDB7DDBF-E298-4B68-8567/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libskia_ios.framework/libskia_ios
kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 1240) - [deny-mmap] mapped file has team identifier 67CU: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BDB7DDBF-E298-4B68-8567/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libskia_ios.framework/libskia_ios
```

After searching online, it seems like the solution would be to sign the framework as well:

`codesign -f --deep -s "Customer Certificate" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libskia_ios.framework`

However, even after doing that, the application still crashes with the same error. Any ideas what else can be changed? I've attached the full start up crash log if that provides any extra insight.

**------ Full error of startup crash ------------**

```
SpringBoard[47] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
SpringBoard[47] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
SpringBoard[47] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[1240] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C893244B-079E-4B43-8F20-5A2 (sandbox)
kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 1240) - [deny-mmap] mapped file does not the same team identifier as main process: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BDB7DDBF-E298-4B68-8567/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libskia_ios.framework/libskia_ios
kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 1240) - [deny-mmap] process has team identifier U78696: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BDB7DDBF-E298-4B68-8567/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libskia_ios.framework/libskia_ios
kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 1240) - [deny-mmap] mapped file has team identifier 67CU: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BDB7DDBF-E298-4B68-8567/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libskia_ios.framework/libskia_ios
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:U78696.com.ng.cort[0x5e49][1240]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
assertiond[60] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 1240: (os/kern) failure (5)
SpringBoard[47] <Warning>: Unable to register for exec notifications: No such process
SpringBoard[47] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 1240: (os/kern) failure (5)
SpringBoard[47] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x19d5eb60; U78696.com.ng.cort; pid: 1240>
SpringBoard[47] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:U78696.com.ng.cort[0x5e49]' crashed.
SpringBoard[47] <Warning>: Application '(null)' exited for an unknown reason.
ReportCrash[1241] <Error>: assertion failed: 13F69: libsystem_trace.dylib + 15927 [FCFC8D6B-F8E1-3577-84A7-8A591C88D8]: 0x0
Unknown[1241] <Error>: 

ReportCrash[1241] <Error>: Process:             MyApp [1240]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BDB7DDBF-E298-4B68-8567/MyApp.app/MyApp
    OS Version:          iOS 9.3.2 (13F69)
ReportCrash[1241] <Error>: Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
    Triggered by Thread:  0
ReportCrash[1241] <Error>: Dyld Error Message:
    Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/libskia_ios.framework/libskia_ios
    Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/BDB7DDBF-E298-4B68-8567/MyApp.app/MyApp
    Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BDB7DDBF-E298-4B68-8567/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libskia_ios.framework/libskia_ios: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BDB7DDBF-E298-4B68-8567/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libskia_ios.framework/libskia_ios'
        Dyld Version: 390.7
ReportCrash[1241] <Error>: Error Formulating Crash Report:
    Failed while requesting activity/breadcrumb diagnostics
```

Comment: Check *entitlements.plist* if it has the old team identifier.Look out for the values of following keys *applicationIdentifier*, *com.apple.developer.team-identifier*,*keychain-access-groups*.Change it and resign the app again and lemme know

Comment: You can find your team identifier from the certificate installed in keychain.do *Get Info* on it and look the value for *User Id*

Comment: Did it solve your problem ?